# how are the leaf values of xgboost regression trees relate to the prediction

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost

It seems that the sum of corresponding leaf values of each tree doesn't equal to the prediction. Here is a sample code:

```
X = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.linspace(-10, 10, 10)})
y = X['x'] * 2
model = xgb.XGBRegressor(booster='gbtree', tree_method='exact', n_estimators=100, max_depth=1).fit(X, y)
Xtest = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.linspace(-20, 20, 101)})
Ytest = model.predict(Xtest)
plt.plot(X['x'], y, 'b.-')
plt.plot(Xtest['x'], Ytest, 'r.')
```

[image]

The tree dumps reads:

```
model.get_booster().get_dump()[:2]

['0:[x<0] yes=1,no=2,missing=1\n\t1:leaf=-2.90277791\n\t2:leaf=2.65277767\n',
 '0:[x<2.22222233] yes=1,no=2,missing=1\n\t1:leaf=-1.90595233\n\t2:leaf=2.44333339\n']
```

If I only use one tree to do prediction:

```
Ytest2 = model.predict(Xtest, ntree_limit=1)
plt.plot(XX1['x'], Ytest2, '.')
np.unique(Ytest2)  # array([-2.4028,  3.1528], dtype=float32)
```

[image]

Clearly, `Ytest2`'s unique values does not corresponds to the leaf value of the first tree, which is `-2.90277791` and `2.65277767`, although the observed split point is right at 0.

1. How are the leaf values related to the predictions?
2. Why are the leaf values in the first tree not symmetric, provided that the input is symmetric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Before* fitting the first tree, xgboost makes an initial prediction.  This is controlled by the parameter `base_score`, which defaults to 0.5.  And indeed, `-2.902777 + 0.5 ~=-2.4028` and `2.652777 + 0.5 ~= 3.1528`.

That also explains your second question: the differences from that initial prediction are *not* symmetric.  If you set `learning_rate=1` you probably could get the predictions to be symmetric after one round, or you could just set `base_score=0`.

Comment: I actually tested `model.base_score` which returns `None`. How to get the `base_score` used?

Comment: xgb is a little weird in setting the python defaults always to `None`, then setting the real default value in its lower-level code. I haven't found where it does that yet, but the docs do advertise the default as 0.5, and the arithmetic checks out in your case.  (Can you call `predict` with `n_tree_limit=0`?)