# Summing the values of leafs in XGBRegressor trees do not match prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

It was my understanding that the final prediction of an XGBoost model (in this particular case an XGBRegressor) was obtained by summing the values of the predicted leaves [[1]](https://discuss.xgboost.ai/t/xgboost-trees-understanding/1822) [[2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/502000/how-prediction-of-xgboost-correspond-to-leaves-values)]. Yet I'm failing to match the prediction summing the values. Here is a MRE:

```
import json
from collections import deque

import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_diabetes
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import xgboost as xgb


def leafs_vector(tree):
    """Returns a vector of nodes for each tree, only leafs are different of 0"""

    stack = deque([tree])

    while stack:
        node = stack.popleft()
        if "leaf" in node:
            yield node["leaf"]
        else:
            yield 0
            for child in node["children"]:
                stack.append(child)


# Load the diabetes dataset
diabetes = load_diabetes()
X, y = diabetes.data, diabetes.target

# Split the dataset into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Define the XGBoost regressor model
xg_reg = xgb.XGBRegressor(objective='reg:squarederror',
                          max_depth=5,
                          n_estimators=10)

# Train the model
xg_reg.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Compute the original predictions
y_pred = xg_reg.predict(X_test)

# get the index of each predicted leaf
predicted_leafs_indices = xg_reg.get_booster().predict(xgb.DMatrix(X_test), pred_leaf=True).astype(np.int32)

# get the trees
trees = xg_reg.get_booster().get_dump(dump_format="json")
trees = [json.loads(tree) for tree in trees]

# get a vector of nodes (ordered by node id)
leafs = [list(leafs_vector(tree)) for tree in trees]

l_pred = []
for pli in predicted_leafs_indices:
    l_pred.append(sum(li[p] for li, p in zip(leafs, pli)))

assert np.allclose(np.array(l_pred), y_pred, atol=0.5) # fails
```

I also tried adding the default value (`0.5`) of the `base_score` (as written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68000028/how-are-the-leaf-values-of-xgboost-regression-trees-relate-to-the-prediction)) to the total sum but it also didn't work.

```
l_pred = []
for pli in predicted_leafs_indices:
    l_pred.append(sum(li[p] for li, p in zip(leafs, pli)) + 0.5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that even is the parameter `base_score` of the model is None, it can have a `base_score` (different of the default one) [[1]](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/9347).

> In addition, the model.base_score will continue to be None as
> discussed in #8634. In summary, the Python attribute base_score is a
> user parameter according to the sklearn interface and should not be
> changed by the library itself. To see the configured base score, you
> either have to use the

To access the `base_score` value the following works in version 2.0.3 of XGBoost

```
config = json.loads(model.get_booster().save_config())
base_score = float(config["learner"]["learner_model_param"]["base_score"])
```

Adding the `base_score` to the total sum make it match the predicted value